# Chrome overwritting my css style?

Tags: wordpress, css, google-chrome

It works perfectly in Firefox, the inspection shows it's affecting the .search-input class, yet it doesn't show the background color, it shows a border, and basically the only things that are showing are the height, width and padding.

[How it looks in Chrome](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/4630/wtfkhe.jpg)

[How it looks in Firefox (correct form)](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/7904/wtfso.jpg)

There's no conflict in the theme, absolutely no results come out when searching for #abadb3 (the border's color). It's like if google was overwritting my css perhaps?

I'm using google chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m

The markup:

```
.topbar > div .search-input {
height:49px;
border:none;
width:49px;
background-color:#F00;
background-image:url(img/i_magni.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:49px;
float:right;    
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;}

.topbar .search-input:focus {
width:310px;
padding-left:55px;
background-position:bottom left;}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: No posted code (markup/CSS) makes it more difficult for us to even start seeing the details of the issue. The descriptions of what you want it to be like versus how it actually is are a little vague. We can't even be 100% sure of which element in the image you're talking about. Since you know how to open and poke around in the dev tools, have you tried looking at the computed style of that element (at the top of the styles on the right) or maybe even expanding the border rule to see if any sub-rules are overridden?

Comment: You just need to see how the image shows background-color:#F00 yet the color is white (and the image isn't white either). The element is the one selected in the chrome inspection. There are 0 evidences about it being overridden, I cannot find the color code of the input border seen in the image and the css specifies that the styles should apply to the .topbar .search-input ones. The computed style shows the background should be red too.

Comment: Edited my post adding markup and Firefox screenshot. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you've figured it out, which it looks like you have, you are encouraged to post your solution as an answer and then accept it!

Comment: Can't yet, it tells me to wait 7 hours as I don't have the reputation apparently. Thanks for the suggestion though, will do as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, apparently you need to add -webkit-appearance: none; for it to work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```